# Javascript Prompt To calculate string length

Tags: javascript, object, prompt

I'm learning javascript at Codeacademy and I am trying to calculate string length from a prompt entry and display a custom alert for each answer. Here is what I have so far:

```
var answer = prompt('What is your surname?').length;

var responses = {
answer > 5: 'Your name has fewer than five characters',
answer < 5: 'Your name has more than five characters',
defaultResponse: 'You didn\'t answer?'
}

alert(responses[answer] || responses.defaultResponse);
```

should I be placing an if statement in here somewhere. Or would a *Switch* be better here?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a clean way to do it:

```
var answer = prompt('What is your surname?');
var response;

if(answer.length == 0){
    response = 'You didn\'t answer?';
} else if(answer.length > 5){
    response = 'Your name has fewer than five characters';
} else if (answer.length < 5) {
    response = 'Your name has more than five characters';
}

alert(response);
```

For something like that, I wouldn't bother with a switch.

Comment: if (answer.length > 5) { response = "Your name has more than 5 characters";

Comment: Thanks for catching that! Edited :)

Comment: also the var response = 'You didn\'t answer?' will never be called, because if they don't enter in a name it is considered a string with the length of 0. And if you cancel the script ends.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use an object to look up for the answer you may do it like this

```
var answer = prompt('What is your surname?').length;

var responses = {
more: 'Your name has more than five characters',
less: 'Your name has fewer than five characters',
default: 'You didn\'t answer?'
}

alert(answer == 0 && responses.default || answer < 5 && responses.less || answer > 5 && responses.more);
```

Comment: Thank you. I was hoping to see a solution using an object.